# How to use SetSelection for Android with toString Override?

Tags: android, overriding, android-spinner, tostring

So here's my issue. I did an override for the toString method so I can just show the name of an object in an listview. So that works. The problem is that my items are stored in an array. So when I use the setSelection for a Spinner, its taking the toString Override for the name of the object. My object does have other properties like Category which I want to use for my Spinner but I can't because its already overridden for a different purpose of the app. Any suggestions would be nice. Thank you.

Comment: please share some code

Comment: @Carlitos Please share some code about ur spinner and object class.